# What is grammatical structure in this Korean sentence?

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence as follows:

> 어떤 장갑으로 **사다 줄까요**? 원하는 것이 있어요.

I don't see grammatical structure "동사 + 다 + 다른 동사" in Korean. As i know, "다" is verb ending in Korean, so "사다 줄까요" is not correct, right? And if this grammatical structure is correct, can you explain how to use it for me? (sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here -다 is short for [-다가](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=8306100), which can be used to connect two verbs.

As for "사다 주다", I think it is used frequently enough to be considered a fixed idiom.  It means the same as "사주다".

Edit: Actually, I realized that they aren't exactly the same.  "사주다" is "to buy for someone", but "사다(가) 주다" is "to buy, and then give it to someone".  So, "사다 주다" would be natural when buying and giving happen separately.  E.g.,:

> (In a shop): 이 과자 사줄까? = Shall I buy this cookie for you?
>
> (Going out for shopping): 과자 좀 사다 줄까? = Shall I buy (and bring home) some cookies for you?

Also, "사주다" can be used when buying itself is an act of favor, so for example a merchant can say "이것 좀 사주세요", which would mean "would you please buy this".

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, the sentence above is not correct. It should more be like

> 어떤 장갑으로 사줄까요?

Comment: any reason why you think it might be incorrect?